# AWS Cognito gives BadRequest error while trying to sign in

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I was trying to implement the AWS cognito spring boot example as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito).

I'm getting the below error while clicking on "Login with Amazon Cognito":

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The server did not understand the operation that was requested.","type":"client"}
```

And the URI is:

```
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{my-pool-id}/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={my-client-id}&scope=openid&state=NHfXN1aWjqUWiRBp0FZzIoZYHx-EmcuUp8sGDKUaODs%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito&nonce=CgC_P_GCnLlHQ4W_9nT04hzwkjaDdPGs7OaLaklP0wU
```

The below configurations are verified myself while troubleshooting the issue.

1. client id, client secret, pool id, region etc. are exactly as configured in my AWS console. No error here.
2. I'm using Cognito provided UI for sign in. Domain already added and verified that cognito UI is redirecting to login screen.
3. Callback URI in app client settings is same as redirect-ui in my config.

My sample config file is linked [here](https://gist.github.com/rahul-raj/5ee771b7863bdabe5fe7d4c180cd8ae0) for reference.

Can you tell me what's going wrong here? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.

For me, I did two things wrong, and fixed by doing followings:

1. Enable identity providers at app client setting
2. Specify domain name (which I did not use at all in spring setting)

Comment: Adding a custom domain (even without certificate) SOLVED my issue.
Referring to the discovery well known endpoint like this: https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{pool_id}/.well-known/openid-configuration
This endpoint will return all oauth endpoints with your pre-defined custom domain.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling wrong `Authorize` endpoint, instead of being

`https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{my-pool-id}/authorize`

it should be

`https://{your-custom-domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize`

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

https://github.com/rieckpil/blog-tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-aws-cognito-thymeleaf

application.yml :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: ${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}
            clientSecret: ${COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope: openid, email
            redirectUriTemplate: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            clientName: spring-boot-backend
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_q0EMn8pPG
            userNameAttribute: cognito:username
```

My openid connect config :

[image]

Make sure that http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito is listed on the Callback URL(s)

[image]

Make sure you set the right client id and secret

[image]

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>de.rieckpil.blog</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-aws-cognito-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-security-aws-cognito-thymeleaf</name>
  <description>Demo project using AWS Cognito with Spring Security</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Web Security Config :

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }


}
```

Worked for me